Freezing Kabobs before grilling, vegies and meat?
Can i freeze marinated chicken kabobs, including vegies on skewers. Then grill them

You might be better off asking how to accomplish whatever reason you have for doing this (to avoid prep on the day of a party; to make them ahead and then cook a few off when you want them; etc)

Houseboat trip. I need to freeze items to take and then grill them a couple days later

I read somewhere that you can freeze kabobs (with vegies) and cook them right on the grill. I am not sure about this method.

if you have some time before your trip, I would recommend doing a small test batch, freezing them, and then try cooking them and see if they’re acceptable.  As another alternative, you might consider freezing meat-only skewers, as onions, peppers, etc hold up for a few days at room temperature, so you could assemble them at the last minute (and cooking is easier as you then don’t have to worry about the meat or veggies over cooking or visa-versa

Frame challenge:
Freeze the meat, keep the veggies whole and unfrozen, they will keep.
To prepare the veggies, you just need a knife and something to cut on, nothing too difficult. Then assemble the skewers just prior to grilling, again nothing too demanding, and you can deposit them right onto the grill.

And honestly, I'd even consider keeping the meat and marinade separate, and only combine them on the day of grilling (depending on the kind of marinade).

If you freeze the meat and marinade together, then you can let it marinade as it thaws out.  (But you want a marinade that can go for a day, not something so acidic that it’s a problem if goes for 4+ hours).  Freezing wet meat is also going to have less issues with freezer burn.

Can you?  Yes.  Will the quality suffer?  Yes.
The vegetables are going to be the most affected… the cell walls are likely to burst when frozen, then be limp, unappetizing things when thawed.  And the moisture release will make them steam rather than develop some charred bits.
You also have to consider how you’re going to go from the freezer to cooking… are you going to cook them from frozen?  Are you going to let them thaw fully (which will take many hours to thaw safely in the fridge) before cooking?
